# How to wrap an ElasticSearch filter in a query

Tags: elasticsearch

In order to use the [percolator](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html) in ElasticSearch, I need to index search queries. However, we mainly use filters for searching. In order to index these filters, they have to be [wrapped inside a query](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/NF24hTwtFVg).

I know of two different approaches to accomplish this. Wrap the filter in a [filtered query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html):

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": { ... }
    }
  }
}
```

or using a [constant_score query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html):

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": { ... }
    }
  }
}
```

Which method is preferred? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While both will yield the same results, and should have very close performance, I'd prefer using the `filtered`-query. It communicates the intention quite clearly. A few months down the road you may be starting at the same query and wonder why you cared about scores. :)

Comment: I agree that the `filtered`-query states the purpose better. Regarding the performance, on what do you base your statement that both should have similar performance?

Comment: An Elasticsearch `filtered`-query with a `match_all`-query (or no query), is actually evaluated using an `XConstantScoreQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/constant-score-vs-filtered-and-a-follow-up-about-custom-filters-score/15182),  "A filtered query with a match_all query is automatically converted internally to a constant_score one". So sounds like the best option is to use `constant_score` and omit an internal step.